# Cannot retrieve public posts from facabook {page-id}/tagged API

Tags: facebook-graph-api

I am attempting to retrieve tagged public posts through /tagged API with a page access token will not return some public tagged posts.
I have found that the available Facebook API https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/page/tagged return posts from the pages only if those pages are authentic.
How can we retrieve post from above facebook Graph API without having an authentic page?
do facebook provide any workaround for developer to test this API ?
Any help would be appreciated..

Comment: By “authentic”, you mean verified? When you say “you found”, do you mean this is mentioned in the docs somewhere (where?), or is that your own conclusion? As far as testing goes, have you checked how it behaves when you try with two pages that the user both has admin access to?

Comment: yes by authentic , it means verified (with blue mark) , yes it is mentioned in the facebook feed api document in limitations section (tagged posts)(https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v10.0/page/feed) . also I have tried test scenario mentioned in your comment, but received null data,  I have a business requirement to get tagged post through API.

Comment: Have you tried tagging a page as a user on your own profile, and checked if you get any results for that?

Comment: Thanks, yes if user with admin rights tagged my page on their page post, this is getting retrieved with /tagged API, but if page tagged in comment of any post, it is not getting retrieved.

Comment: Not sure whether this endpoint is supposed to cover mentions in comments in the first place, I think it might return posts only.